# Getting data using mirth by schedule

Tags: schedule, mirth

I need get patients data every day several times - in 9 am, 12 pm and 3 pm.

Where I can setup this in Mirth?

I looked to chanel setup, but do not find any acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting lies in the source tab of the channel setup. Assuming your channel source connector is Database reader or a file reader.

Set the Polling type as `Time` instead of interval. That will ask you to specify a particular day time eg 11:15 AM and everyday at that time the data will be polled.

If you are talking about 3 hours gap then set the polling type as `interval` and put the value of `108000 ms(1000*6*6*3)` in polling frequency.

Comment: Can the Polling type be set if the channel source connector is Not a Database reader or a file reader? If so how can this be achieved?

Comment: I think that setting is applicable for all types of source connector except for Channel Reader and JS reader.